# How to extract a word that could possibly be followed with another word

Tags: regex

I want to extract [games, games, things, things] from
the following array.

```
Today_games
Today_games_freq
Today_things
Today_things_freq
```

I have tried `Today_(\w+)(?=_freq)?`
Which will give me the extra "freq"
And some other combinations, but I couldn't figure out how to get just after the first hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Today_(\w+?)(?:_freq)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X69SZE/1). This matches `Today_`, then captures any one or more word chars (as few as possible) into Group 1 (with `(\w+?)`), and then `(?:_freq)?$` matches an optional occurrence of a `_freq` substring and asserts the position at the end of string.

Or,

```
Today_([^\W_]+)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X69SZE/2).

Here, `Today_` is matched and the `([^\W_]+)` pattern captures one or more alphanumeric chars into Group 1 (same as `\w+` with `_` subtracted from `\w`).

Comment: I think this is a more general example I am looking for: 
```Today_(\w+?)(?:_freq)?$```

because it will also match `grocery_net` if I want to extract from the following:
Today_grocery_net
Today_grocery_net_freq

Comment: @LSM That would be a good additional information to include into the question, and since it is not there, both solutions are viable at the moment.